# Generator Stator Cover Purpose

Tags: electrical, generator

I recently purchased a generator and upon receiving it, and comparing it to the picture on the box, removed the black stator cover. Did I do something I shouldn't have? Is the stator cover necessary, and if so, what is its purpose?

[image: Blue arrow pointing at the black cover that was removed]

Comment: How about a picture  of the motor with the cover removed. Did the instructions call for the removal of the cover?  Did you contact the manufacturer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its just a dust/environmental cover which you probably want for a generator that runs outside, but a pic would be nice.  Why was it removed?

Comment: It's to help the generator make it past the returns period. It is so you don't see the rust that will bloom on the laminations quite soon...

Comment: Modern TFEC motors and alternator are totally enclosed fan cooled, the shield reduced the chance of moisture weeping through the laminated iron. They are dipped but the dip breaks down on the laminations long before the varnish on the wire, a damp core can cause a early failure in some cases.